# Problem with tipa \textnrleg

Tags: beamer, tipa

[image]The expected "long leg n" turns out as "6".`how come the words after the long leg n will appear in next line?
{where l is the log likelihood function,\\
\mathnrleg is the vector of nuisance parameters,\\
($\hat{\theta}$,$\hat{\mathnrleg}$) is the maximum likelihood estimator of($\theta$,$\mathnrleg$),\\
$\tilde{\mathnrleg}$ is the restricted maximum likelihood estimator of  $\mathnrleg$ under $\text {H}_0.$}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\textcolor{blue}{\underline {Likelihood Ratio Method}}
\begin{itemize}
\item For a scalar parameter of interest $\theta$, the likelihood ratio statistic for testing the null hypothesis, $\text{H}_0$: $\theta$= $\theta_0$ versus $\text{H}_1$: $\theta$ $\neq$ $\theta_0$ is given as,
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} 
$$\Psi=2[l(\hat{\theta},\hat{\textipa{\textnrleg}}$$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please provide a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that actually results in this problem.  that will give helpers something concrete to work with.  otherwise, they'll have to construct a test themselves, and that could involve a lot of useless guessing.

Comment: Please do not use edits to ask new questions.

Comment: i thought it's related with the \textnrleg as the problem appear after this too

Comment: Nobody will see the new question hidden in your old. Also please provide a MWE that reproduces the problem and not just code fragments.

Comment: why my mwe will all squeeze together when i post it out? sorry i am new here

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to use the “long tailed n” as a math symbol, define a command for it. Since `\textnrleg` is supposed to appear in text, add `\textnormal` around it. Using `\text` is not sufficient, because the `tipx` font lacks other shapes and you'd get again a 6 if you use just `\text{\textnrleg}` in an italic or boldface context.

I minimized the code, as `beamer` is not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}

\newcommand{\mathnrleg}{\textnormal{\textnrleg}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Psi=2[l(\hat{\theta},\hat{\mathnrleg}
\]
\end{document}
```

Don't use, under any circumstances, `$$` in a LaTeX document.

[image]

Comment: thanks it works! can i know why i shoudnt use $$? i thought it's for equation

Comment: @yap See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)